# How to block a specific IP in Packetbeat

Tags: logstash, packetbeat

So I am doing a data visualization of netflow traffic, and I am running packetbeat in "af mode" to gather all of the netflow data.

The problem is that the IP that I am connecting to the box with packetbeat on it, is something I want to ignore. Since I know what it is and it is just cluttering things up in the visualization.

I want to ignore all of the traffic that has this data:

"dest.ip" of < XYZ > 
and 
"source.ip" of < IP of server running packetbeat >

I have the "packetbeat.ignore_outgoing: true" set up in my packetbeat.yml file. I am running this on CentOS and outputting the packetbeat data straight to Logstash.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you just sending the data to logstash or are you preprocessing it in filebeat?

Comment: Yes I am, I ended up writing a Logstash filter. I just wanted to know if there was some kind of config option in filebeat, to get rid of it before it even gets sent to Logstash.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was writing a Logstash filter.

```
 filter {
  if[type] == "flow" and [dest][ip] == "192.168.X.Y" and [packet_source][ip] == "192.168.Z.D" {
        drop { }
  }
}
```